# Xamarin Android fragment + ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, xamarin.android

does anyone have an example of these 3 working together?

1. A fully programmatic Fragment comprised of
2. Programatically created ListView using a
3. Custom ListAdapter

When I attempt to do so, the adapter's GetView is never called - even though Count property is indeed called and returns > 0.

When I splice in an ArrayAdapter instead to test, things work as expected.